# extJs cannot find relative path of libraries

Tags: eclipse, extjs

I created dynamic web project in eclipse and want to use extjs. I added my extjs folder into the project folder and added

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
```

into my HTML file but it can not find it.

Can somebody help?

Comment: are u deploying onto a web server?

Comment: i'm using tomcat. but i didn't add anything..

Comment: have you added your extjs directory structure directly under your webapp folder? ie. webapp\extjs\resources\etc..

Comment: yes. should I add it in WebContent folder instead?

Comment: no. let me make a screenshot of my setup, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it set up. I'm using Webstorm (not eclipse), but principle should be the same. I have my extJS in a seperate project. Under my folder webapp\js\lib\ I have the extJS library

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: no :-( this is an error: GET http://localhost:8080/Fits/extjs/ext-all.js 404 (Not Found) this is a link  <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>              I put extjs just under Fits folder.

Comment: but this has nothing to do with extjs. Try creating a file test.html and putting it in the extjs folder. You just need to get your paths right.

Comment: and try href="../extjs/resources/". Is your extjs folder directly under webapp?

Comment: I tried to use absolute path also but it gives an error: it's not permitted. That i should use relative path instead

Comment: if you create a test.html file and put it under webapp, do you see that file?